# use typescript generics to infer type of param function

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics

```
function validate<K>(validationFunc: (...args: (K extends Array<infer T> ? T : K)[]) => boolean, validationArgs: K[]): boolean {
  let res: boolean;
  for (const validationArg of validationArgs) {
    if (Array.isArray(validationArg)) {
      res = validationFunc(...validationArg);
    } else {
      // res = validationFunc(validationArg);
      res = (validationFunc as (args: K) => boolean)(validationArg);
    }
    if(!res) 
      return false;
  }
  return true
}
```

The commented line throws an Error at the argument: `the Argument of type 'K' is not assignable to parameter of type 'K extends (infer T)[] ? T : K'.ts(2345)`, whereas the casted version works, and does not throw any errors.
As seen in [this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABANwIYBsYBNVQKYA8A0gHwAUAUItShtrvGAGLgQBciZAdD6gE4BzAM4cyRRHgAe+MFiGIAgnz6oAngRhhgePogAqJRAH59iDkQCUAbQC6FxAF5DAIzhx0eVGAA0VGmkwcWAQlYXNbCgsOV3dPMABvPxoPKEQ+PBFEGI8vAG4-YDhdMggEIVSA+mCwUMQ4YFpAhhDBIXtEmkQYBrIlFVUuGCE+tTJKoMZQi3akmnT5B0aqxhZIbh5x5prBC3zOgF8JdCE8RA7OtIzHJYmEVYgxulvtgV3Z6gB6D8uFzk3q+6IVDyMj8MKISyOFxuHJgCyPJrVKZ7Gj7WbdMgAQnm9nelygID4SGAGBOKLRnXSBKJiCgfBAeHyaIo-zwZDIkg4YBAAFtnDp7E5EJJEABSRAAJkcDkWAAZvIgrABGBUShUAZjsLKeuDZoI45T4mgECucBrpxsFhlQ0sWzgVVisAHJUE6FS6nTYHU7nG7ED7PVrWezOYhuXyBVDhWLJbbEPLFR73b6gzr8CGubz+XwrdHxVKZXKHc7Xe7XV7E77k4GLBQgA).

Why is typescript not able to infer, that on this line, `K` cannot be of type `Array<any>` and thus is allowed to be passed to the validation function?

Semantically:
If the second argument is of type `K[]`, the function needs to accept `K` as a single parameter.
If the second argument is of type `K[][]`, the function needs to accept multiple arguments of `K`.

E.g.

`validate((x: number) => x%2, [1, 2, 3])` should be ok

`validate((a: string, b: string) => a === b, [['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b']])` should be ok

`validate((x: number) => x%2, ['a', 'b'])` should throw an error

`validate((x: number) => x%2, [['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b']])` should throw an error

EDIT:
`validate((x: number) => x % 2 === 0, [[1, 2, 3]])` should also throw an error, since validate would destructure the `number[][]` once, and try to call `(x: number) => boolean` with `number[]`

Comment: I [tested it on TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwDcoItgoMQAeAaQD4AKAKHhcONPN1QDE0wAuePQB0o2AHMAzoPrV4IAB4VUwSfACCMGFACelLKkQgY8ACq14AfjPxB1AJQBtALr34AXgsAjHDgggoVAAaZlYiEjJsPE0pOxdGe0EfPwDURkZwjgp6egVBVGQAWy9jN094BXgAUngAJg93d3gABiD4RwBGNtq2gGZXDPZIkByoQUkMGANxNq9xyemyiygGpq82x0cAcigttp2t5w2trz34E8OBzOGcvPgC4tKPC0qa+sam1vaD-dOrofII1y+SKJRgSwq1TqqxaG22u32uyO31Ov0u9kYQA) and I get what you expect. Which version/compiler options of TS do you use?

Comment: I use the latest version `3.6.4`. The examples are just to illustrate, what I want to achieve semantically. The problem is not the method-declaration (works fine in my code and the playground). The problem is in the body. I think I should not be required to cast the `validationFunc`. The issue becomes visible in playground (line 10) (see edit in question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to infer the type of the param function. Your validation arguments can be just `K[] | K[][]` as you explained it.

I also did a small change when you call the validate function `x % 2` should be wrapped in `Boolean()` otherwise the return value would be incorrect.

```
function validate<T extends (...args: any) => boolean, P extends Parameters<T>>(validationFunc: T, validationArgs: P[]): boolean {
  let res: boolean;

  for (const validationArg of validationArgs) {
    res = validationFunc(validationArg);
    if(!res) 
      return false;
  }
  return true
}

function simplified<T extends (...args: any) => boolean, P extends Parameters<T>>(validationFunc: T, validationArgs: P[]): boolean {
  return validationArgs.every((args) => validationFunc(args));
}

validate((x: number) => Boolean(x % 2), [[1], [2], [3]]) // should be ok

validate((a: string, b: string) => a === b, [['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b']]) // should be ok

validate((x: number) => Boolean(x % 2), [['a'], ['b']]) // should throw an error

validate((x: number) => Boolean(x % 2), [['a', 'a'], ['b', 'b']]) // should throw an error

validate((x: number) => x % 2 === 0, [[1, 2, 3]]); // should throw an error
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=8&ssc=4&pln=3&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABANwIYBsYBNVQKYA8AKongB75hYDOiAFAHROoBOA5tQFyKpgCeASkQBeAHyIARnDjo8vADSIACqQp4qtJa1QBbPPhbVio0XTSYcsBADFwEbkUXnsueGACC7LsoDaAXQFuKRk5JABvAFgAKEREWShEFjxvYNleAG5o6NjgOBZ6CARqBOdLN082RDhgFAwXKw8vIUiY2MTkkVqLVxs7MzqyhAqBTNbYmGA6AEIk6iFsttikqBAWJGAMajxR2IBfBeXVpCgWEDxo-ajo0EgGxGoYHQAHTGAYPCxiVUoaeiYGVgcbi8QQicSpUKKFTkH6abR6AxGIgmfrdBq2SAOJwDHqNIG+AJBaRpcIHfRHLr1cpeBh4ZB4Fh8Oh0QFzMGUwZgDEQFlNEYXLJRUq4PDMsjcMAgHQSBlCMSIABCxNCdDIiAApIgAEwCRQ+HwARj8eq1xsQPgAzH4AogAPS2+4ACzgIHQWEkeCqAGtBcL8MzUNxiiwYGA2IoJEGTqG2HLxKgRMJhJI9T4AOSoNOKDNps3piRZxBpgvWoT2p0ut0e72+nH+1USqUylhxxXK3iqjXa3Xm9OZvPF3M28vUZ2u91QR0sOAAdx4SAZ05YtbRoobiEl0tl7KVIQ7as1OtTOez-b1g+zJeHDtHlYnU9n89ILCXK-qa-FG6b2-lB+1ieTAAGVMDUULVFCtAJ0jtG8xyrSdpznXhn1fKIgA)

Comment: okay, I added another Example which is not caught with an error if I don`t infer the inner type. sorry, I missed that earlier. If that'd not be the case, your solution works fine, but may cause an error at runtime. (with mine neither)

Comment: Edited, but needed to make some change, I don't think what you're trying to achieve is possible, if someone finds a better answer I'm curious myself.. :) I think it's ambiguous when you provide `[1, 2, 3]` as argument as it can be for one execution of a function with 3 params or 3 execution of a function with 1 param.

Comment: Also added a simplified version, you might just be able to do this with `Array.every()`.

Comment: @Grabofus, Its not in my opinion. I always provide an Array. Each item in this Array will be used for one Iteration. Iff the items in this Outer Array, are themselves Arrays, they should be spread and passed as individual args to the validationFunc. `[1, 2, 3]` -> three iterations with 1 number each `validationFunc(x)` ; `[[1, 2, 3]]` => one call only to `vaildationFunc(1,2,3)`.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik `every` is the same as a negated `some`, it'll stop on the first `false`

Comment: @Grabofus true. Stupid me. I must've had a hangover... ;)